# extracting only relevant comments from a list of comments

Tags: r, text-mining

Continuing with my exploration into text analysis, i have encountered yet another roadblock.I understand the logic but don't know how to do it in R.
Here's what i want to do:
I have 2 CSVs- 1. contains 10,000 comments   2. containing a list of words
I want to select all those comments that have any of the words in the 2nd CSV. How can i go about it?

example:

```
**CSV 1:**
this is a sample set
the comments are not real
this is a random set of words
hope this helps the problem case
thankyou for helping out
i have learned a lot here
feel free to comment

**CSV 2**
sample
set
comment

**Expected output:**
 this is a sample set
 the comments are not real
 this is a random set of words
 feel free to comment
```

Please note: 
the different forms of words is also considered, eg, comment and comments are both considered.

Comment: both are list of comments and words respectively

Comment: can you make your example reproducible?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `grep` after `paste`ing the elements in the second dataset.

```
v1 <- scan("file2.csv", what ="")
lines1 <- readLines("file1.csv")
grep(paste(v1, collapse="|"), lines1, value=TRUE)
#[1] "this is a sample set"          "the comments are not real" 
#[3] "this is a random set of words" "feel free to comment"
```

Answer (score 0):

First create two objects called `lines` and `words.to.match` from your files. You could do it like this:

```
lines <- read.csv('csv1.csv', stringsAsFactors=F)[[1]]
words.to.match <- read.csv('csv2.csv', stringsAsFactors=F)[[1]]
```

Let's say they look like this:

```
lines <- c(
  'this is a sample set',
  'the comments are not real',
  'this is a random set of words',
  'hope this helps the problem case',
  'thankyou for helping out',
  'i have learned a lot here',
  'feel free to comment'
)
words.to.match <- c('sample', 'set', 'comment')
```

You can then compute the matches with two nested `*apply-`functions:

```
matches <- mapply(
    function(words, line)
        any(sapply(words, grepl, line, fixed=T)),
    list(words.to.match),
    lines
)
matched.lines <- lines[which(matches)]
```

What's going on here? I use `mapply` to compute a function over each line in lines, taking `words.to.match` as the other argument. Note that the cardinality of `list(words.to.match)` is 1. I just recycle this argument across each application. Then, inside the `mapply` function I call an `sapply` function to check whether any of the words match the line (I check for the match via grepl).

This is not necessarily the most efficient solution, but it's a bit more intelligible to me. Another way you could compute `matches` is:

```
matches <- lapply(words.to.match, grepl, lines, fixed=T)
matches <- do.call("rbind", matches)
matches <- apply(matches, c(2), any)
```

I dislike this solution because you need to do a `do.call("rbind",...)`, which is a bit hacky.